# How to fix Appium IOS Simulator Script Error: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, appium

I get this error when running an iOS simulator script on Appium. It doesn't load the Safari browser on the iOS simulator and stops the script with this error. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version ) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

info: [debug] Creating new appium session 868f1127-e0a8-4dd2-9084-7e4141922313

info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Xcode version set to 7.0.1

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"868f1127-e0a8-4dd2-9084-7e4141922313"} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.463 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"868f1127-e0a8-4dd2-9084-7e4141922313"}

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

error: Could not determine iOS SDK version

info: [debug] Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version\n)","cause":{"killed":true,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTERM","cmd":"/bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version"},"isOperational":true,"killed":true,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTERM","cmd":"/bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version","origValue":"Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version\n"},"sessionId":null} info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 9308.575 ms - 525 

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.138 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.675 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.698 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.935 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.653 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.771 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.659 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.822 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.612 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2"}}}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"safari","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"9.0"}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_60) info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION ***

info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION * info: **** NEW SESSION *** info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: [debug] Configuring Safari session info: [debug] We're on iOS8+ so not copying mobile safari app info: [debug] Creating new appium session df61b545-adf4-4d3b-a374-aabc163c4df4 info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

error: Could not determine iOS SDK version

info: [debug] Xcode version set to 7.0.1 info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session info: [debug] undefined info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version\n)","cause":{"killed":true,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTERM","cmd":"/bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version"},"isOperational":true,"killed":true,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTERM","cmd":"/bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version","origValue":"Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version\n"},"sessionId":null} info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 96.128 ms - 525 

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you just run `xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version`?

Comment: When I get home, I will try it out. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Jeremy, it returned 9.0 version.

Comment: Now when I run the same script, I get this error. Command Failed:  /bin/sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments' -s devices

Comment: I reboot and reran the script and it still shows Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-version . But don't know why it worked previously after many retries. It works 1 out of 10 times it seems. Something is wrong. I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?